# Removing duplicates between two workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, worksheet, drop-duplicates

I need help removing duplicates between two workbooks: "Master" workbook and  "Copy" workbook.

I'm looking for values in these columns that are duplicates:

- Copy Column D = Master Column A
- Copy Column O = Master Column C
- Copy Column R = Master Column G
- Copy Column S = Master Column H

If ALL of the conditions above are met, then I'd like to delete that duplicate row from the "Copy" workbook only.

I'm pretty new at VBA, so I've been doing my best but still getting stuck!

Comment: Are the columns text, numeric or date ?

Comment: The first two columns (Copy D, O and Master A, C) are text and the last two columns (Copy R, S and Master G, H) are date

Comment: Please share the code you have created so far and describe how it is not performing exactly as you want. If it will not compile or runs with errors, provide error numbers and text, and on which line

Comment: In which workbook will the code be located? If it is in one of the two, then share the other's full name (incl. path and extension). Otherwise, share the same for both. Also, share where the tables start (e.g. A1) for both workbooks and the names of their worksheets. Add your code, some screenshots of the data, and the rest of the information to your post (not in the comments).